# ConstraintLayout vertical centering in parent with no overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**The space between 'Home' and 'Btn3' should be at the midline of the layout, but I can't figure out how to do that.**

My layout looks like this

[image]

As you can see I have a chain between the two elements (the buttons are in a LinearLayout.)
You can see that the buttons aren't centered vertically in the parent.

The space between 'Home' and 'Btn3' should be at the midline of the layout, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Obviously I can constrain the button layout to top and bottom of parent, but then when the layout rotates & gets smaller we get an overlap like this.

[image]

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff303030"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guide_logo_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guide_logo_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guide_logo_end"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guide_logo_top"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/version_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                android:text="virtual console"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="34px" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/version_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:textColor="#909090"
                android:textSize="28px"
                tools:text="x.x.xx.xxxx" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/enable_disable_btn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/full_day_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Btn1"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/demo_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32px"
                android:background="@drawable/full_day_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/demo_btn3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32px"
                android:background="@drawable/full_day_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Btn3"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/demo_admin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32px"
                android:background="@drawable/full_day_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Admin"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove linearLayout of logo_layout and try to create your layout with constraint layout options, replace relative layout with scrollView, create a vertical chain and use one of this modes, also you can set
android:minHeight="...dp" for your widgets
[image: chain mode]

Comment: Which layout are you saying to replace with the ScrollView? The outer one?

Comment: yes, set scrollView as parent view group

Comment: yes, set scrollView as parent view group

Comment: Huh, yeah adding the ScrollView did it. Strange that it has that behavior. Thanks!